# Qt/C++ Multimedia Player Video Clips, multiple video widgets

Tags: c++, qt, video, video-player, qtmultimedia

I recently installed Qt 5.4 and was going through the documentation
I am new with QT but not C++. I want to implement an app that loads, stop, seek, fast forward and rewind videos.I have to make multiple video widgets. For example I monitor four cameras at my house hold and I want to play them such that I can forward/rewind/stop etc... at the same time with the idea that I create multiple video widgets.

What is the best way to start implementing multiple videos playing in QT with the idea that I can rewind/fast forward/play four videos at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is good to consider using libraries like [QtAV](http://wang-bin.github.io/qtav.org/). It will work for most platforms and  unlike QtMultimedia no additional codecs and plugins are required to install.

QtAV uses FFmpeg and has some interesting features like multiple renderers for 1 player, region of interest(video crop), custom filters, ... that does not exist in QtMultimedia.

It also works fine for both Qt4 and Qt5 and supports most playback functions like play, pause, speed, seek, subtitle, volume, audio channel, video equalizer, network stream, ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have looked at it and now I am using QML and QtMultimedia to do my video